# Copy mapserv.exe problem

Tags: mapserver

I had already formulated an entry recently in which I asked for the error message "msCGILoadMap (): Web application error. CGI variable" map "is not set." asked.

Now I think I have found a more accurate diagnosis. For our project we need several mapserv.exe, because we present different maps to different users (Mapfiles). 
Every time I come up with a new copy of the mapserv.exe this error message follows. Does anyone know this problem? Does something have to be considered when copying the file?

Comment: Why are you using multiple mapserv.exe files, when you can simply use multiple .map files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation decision.

You can have one MapServer executable and different map files

like:

```
http://my_server/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=my_bedrock_geology.map&
http://my_server/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=my_surface_geology.map&
```

or you can have multiple copies of the MapServer executable and use Apache configuration to end up with a structure like:

```
http://my_server/cgi-bin/my_bedrock_geology/mapserv.exe?
http://my_server/cgi-bin/my_surface_geology/mapserv.exe?
```

Take a look at the [OneGeology documentatio](https://onegeology-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providingdata.html#using-mapserver)n for an example of how to configure the latter